# Get POST Request Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to get the response from my POST form with Symfony, but the 'name' variable is always returning null? Been stuck on this for hours and would appreciate some help.

I am using $request->request->get('...', 'default') as stated in the documentation.

```
{
    $project = new Project();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Load Project'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        return $this->render('default/show.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $request->request->get('name', 'null'),
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to read a `POST` variable from the `GET` array! Try using `request->post` instead

Comment: Try this 

`if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
$project = $form->getData(); 
        return $this->render('default/show.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $project->getName(),
        ));
    }`

Comment: @Antony this is not how Symfony works ! $request->request is an equivalent of php superglobal $_POST. So calling $request->request->get('name') is like calling $_POST['name'] in native php

Comment: @OlivierC How does Symfony differenciate `GET` and `POST` in this case? I'm not familiar with the framework

Comment: @Anthony Symfony equivalent to $_GET is $request->query. get() in the above exemple is actually a standard getter method

Comment: @Ben In your browser look at the html source code or maybe use F12 to look at what is actually posted.  You might be amused to find out that Symfony actually changes the name of form elements.  Which is why your approach is failing.  It's also one reason why I avoid the form component.  Oliverc has the right answer.

Comment: Try this: $request->query->get('variable'); or $request->request->get('variable');

Comment: @rescobar While the form component does change the name of the form element, it is not going to change 'name' to 'variable'.  And why would suggest checking the query parameters for a posted form?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of name from your project object:

```
$project = new Project();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Load Project'))
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    return $this->render('default/show.html.twig', array(
        'name' => $project->getName(),
    ));
}

return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

or from the form :

```
$project = new Project();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Load Project'))
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    return $this->render('default/show.html.twig', array(
        'name' => $form->get('name'),
    ));
}

return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```